# Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTException: headless environment error in java

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to use the Robot class, but when I try to run a small piece of code the console returns me an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTException: headless environment

I have seen some solutions, such as " System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");"
but then it responds

> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

My piece of test code:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;


public class AutoSell {
  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException  {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(1000);
        System.out.println("test");
      
        }
    }
```

I am using [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (WSL2) and my program is a java console application.

Comment: You can't run GUI applications on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Maybe this will help. [Run Linux GUI apps on the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) What do you want the `Robot` to do? Do you want it to move the mouse? Or do you want it to simulate pressing keys on the computer keyboard? Or do you want a screen capture? There may be another way to achieve your goal without using `java.awt.Robot`.

Comment: From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html): "_If the current platform configuration does not allow input control, an AWTException will be thrown when trying to construct Robot objects_". Please explain what you are trying to do, because you will likely need to take a different approach.

Comment: @Abra I want the program to use the keyboard to type and use the mouse.

Comment: @Abra Probably because of this automatic translation in chrome.  The application is console-based

Comment: @Abra Do you have anything?

Comment: You can't use class `java.awt.Robot` in a console app in WSL.

Comment: @Abra So what i can do?

Comment: You need to give more details about the task you are trying to achieve without describing how you want to achieve it. Why do [you think that] you need to write to different locations on the terminal window? Are you trying to program some kind of game?